# Fixed images disappearing from 3D transitions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[The site in question](http://fang.ws) uses a lot of `3D transitions`, and when applying a `background-attachment: fixed` to any `background`, it disappears. It seems to have something to do with `backface-visibility`, but removing that simply makes the scrolling buggy.

Comment: You can only use `relative` images, and `fixed` images simply disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand correctly:

To fit the image to full screen, use the CSS property:

```
background-size:100% 100%;
```

However note that it will stretch the image if the size is not correct

use it

```
#skill2 {
    background: url("/assets/img/developer-laptop-desk.jpg") no-repeat fixed center top / 100% 100% rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #000000;
    width: 100%;
}


#intro {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-image: url("/assets/img/backstretch.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I have trouble making the image fixed, and it seems to be an issue with 3D rendering.

Comment: can you specify any class id name or image ?